# Resume download from Download Manager android when download is failed

Tags: android

I am using DownloadManager service to download files. I want it to resume the download if it is failed by any case(for example internet got disconnected). I am saving the download id generated when we enqueue the request for download. Can I resume download using that id? Or with any other method?

EDIT: Code of my Download Service: http://pastie.org/8613353

Comment: Found the answer, the link was not having the resume capability. That's why it wasn't resumed.

Comment: Hi Berserk, can you please share what was the solution to this problem, it ll b e  helpful.Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Andy Thanks to Marcin's suggestion, I checked the docs and found that this link doesn't have the resume capability. That's why it didn't resume. I posted this as an answer too.

Comment: thanks for the reply :) saved my time

Comment: @Andy Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's good habit to check documentation first. DownloadManager [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) says:

> The download manager will conduct the download in the background,
>   taking care of HTTP interactions and retrying downloads after failures
>   or across connectivity changes and system reboots.

Comment: Thanks for reply :) I am continuously monitoring the download manager object I created in my download service using a timer. But it is always showing status_failed. It is not going back to running state.

Comment: can any one please add the working code? I'm not able to find the solution to this problem.

Comment: FWIW, the quote above only talks about retrying, not _resuming_.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Marcin's suggestion, I checked the documentation for DownloadManager. The problem with the link I posted was that it was not having resume capability. That's why after it failed due to internet disconnection, it won't resume. I tried other links with resume capability, and they all resume perfectly after internet re-connection.